# Datatable ajax reload error

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have this table that displays a bootstrap modal with a form inside, when i fill this form and save my data or clicking to close modal, i want to refresh the data table but this caught and error:

TypeError: c is undefined on 64 line of jquery.min.js

this show this error when i refresh the ajax data, this is my code:
{

```
$(function(){
var table = $('').dataTable({
       "bDestroy": true,
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sAjaxSource": '/test/',
       "sDom": 't',
   "bFilter": false,
});
    table.fnClearTable(0);
    table.fnReloadAjax(null, null, false);
});
```

}

and i use the jQuery v1.10.2 and DataTables 1.9.2 versions.

Thanks!

Comment: Would be easier to find solution if you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you include the [fnReloadAjax](https://next.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax) plugin?

`<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="//cdn.datatables.net/plugins/505bef35b56/api/fnReloadAjax.js">
</script>`

link of cdn: [fnRealodAjaxCDN](http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/api/fnReloadAjax.js)

Comment: Yes, i include it, but i found this easy way to reload without errors:

{
`$('id').dataTable().fnReloadAjax();`
}


This fix the problem.

Thank you very much for your help!